# Using "UseDeveloperExceptionPage" together with "UseExceptionHandler"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to show the developer exception page when there is an unhandled exception but I also want to add logging to it. But when I use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage` together with `app.UseExceptionHandler`, only the last one I add works. How can I make the two work together?

Comment: The developer exception page already logs the unhandled exception. What more do you need, specifically?

Answer (score 4):

The default ExceptionHandler does not work with the DeveloperExceptionPage because it catches the Exception.
What you can do is add an ExceptionFilter, log the Exception and let it be caught by the DeveloperExceptionPage:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Log.Error(context.Exception, $"{context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}");

        // the important bit here
        context.ExceptionHandled = false;
    }
}
```

And then add it to the filters:

```
services.AddMvc(setup => { /* ... */ setup.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>(); });
```

Comment: As far as I understand, ExceptionFilter approach is more restricted when compared to the middleware approach and that was why I preferred "UseExceptionHandler". Is this really the case?

Comment: @hakanviv It all depends on what exactly you want to do, but you didn't mention much besides logging

Comment: The main difference you might need to worry about is that the `IExceptionFilter` approach will only apply to the MVC middleware, which means that if you have other middleware, the logging wouldn't run.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Exactly. So what should I do to use both?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to move your logic to an exception filter.

You can simply re-throw the exception received from the `IExceptionHandlerFeature` you used (`IExceptionHandlerFeature`/`IExceptionHandlerPathFeature`)

For example:

```
var exceptionFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
throw exceptionFeature.Error;
```

Then your DeveloperExceptionPage will catch the exception down the pipeline.

Comment: If memory serves that would reset the callstack of the Exception, no?

Comment: @pbarranis Actually after investigating, it doesn't matter what kind of an exception you throw back from inside the alternative pipeline - as long as it gets unhandled, the original exception that got captured by the `UseExceptionHandler` will be rethrown back. And let's not forget that it will always be logged before that. That sounds really cool, but also really dangerous. In reality - if you wanted to modify the exception being thrown and propagate that back to the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, you'd have to introduce a separate `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` in your alternative pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to get the developer exception page when the request is sent with the `text/html` header to make debugging a bit easier.

[SpiritBob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672328/6735035) worked but it changed the route shown in the developer page to the error handling endpoint

[image: Developer exception page with wrong route]

I fixed this by registering the exception handler middleware using a branching request pipeline. Instead of just registering the exception handler like this:

```cs
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error-Development");
}
```

You change it to this:

```cs
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
else
{
    app.UseWhen(
        context =>
        {
            RequestHeaders headers = context.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
            MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = new("text/html");

            return !headers.Accept.Any(h => h.IsSubsetOf(mediaTypeHeaderValue));
        },
        applicationBuilder => applicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandler("/Error-Development"));
}
```

This will use the exception handler middleware unless you include `text/html` in the accept header. In which case, it will allow the exception to bubble up to the developer exception page middleware and return a nicely formatted exception page.